# Copy pasting WPF window gives error

Tags: wpf, xaml

I realized that VS gives error when we try to copy paste one of the window. The errors are usually of type the method call is ambiguous between InitializeComponet() or other methods. This is because that VS only renames xaml files but not the assciated CS files. I dont know why VS dont handle that. What is better way to copy paste the existing windows, that will not give any error. Or is their any simple workaround? What all other things we need to manually rename?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VS renames XAML and the associated CS files as well. What it does not do is change the **class name** and **constructor name** in the CS file and the **x:Class** property in the XAML file. If you change these, this would work fine.

I don't think there is a workaround, but I don't think that it is a lot of work either.

Comment: :(. It recently gave me many errors. And I feel it doesnt renames the class name. Yes you are right it renames the CS file names but not the names of the class (say one extending Window or UserControl) inside the CS files. So if there is any public member inside them them their existence/reference is flagged as ambiguous. This is true for all the controls laid down on window and their event. So this gives a big list of errors if the Window contains many controls. Just try copy pasting one. Dont panic by huge list of errors. You can delete the pasted window and all errors will vanish.